# MySql connection leakage is not happening as per the java code

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, jboss7.x

In MySQL, connection leakage is not happening as per the JSP code. 

Server: JBoss 7 
MySQL version: 5.7 
MySQL-connector-java-5.1.18.jar

To ensure the connection leak from java code, I am getting the below error in the server.log:

[org.jboss.jca.core.api.connectionmanager.ccm.CachedConnectionManager] (http-/0.0.0.0:80-7) IJ000100: Closing a connection for you. Please close them yourself: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6@73a1aa: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE

```
JSP code:

Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Connection conn = null;
DataSource dataSource = null;
try{
        dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/MySql");
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from test.users");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

```
standalone.xml code

<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MySql" pool-name="MySql" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&amp;autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>web</user-name>
        <password>123</password>
    </security>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

I have accessed the above JSP page 50 times and 50 sleep connection should be there in the MySQL process list. But it is not happening. Below are the results:

I have executed the below query in MySQL query browser to identify the connection leak:

select id,host,command,time,info from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.processlist where user = 'web';

Actual Result: It is showing 7 sleep connections only

Expected result: It should be 50 sleep connection

Please help me to understand the behavior and correct it if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your JSP code doesn't close the connection when it it is done. And really, you should be doing things like that in JSP code. And the logged warning means that the connection pool closed it for you. Your connection pool does this to prevent the connection leak from exhausting the pool. But given that reclamation is slower (or in some case: unintended), it is better if you do it yourself. Fix your code, learn about try-with-resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark. As you said, if i enable <cached-connection-manager debug="true"> the jdbc connection has been closed automatically by the help of connection pool. If i not enable, connection leak is happening.  Usually i will use try with resources. But i want to explore how the connection is leaking. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The connection is leaking because you aren't closing it. Closing is what returns it to the connection pool. And using try-with-resources makes it simpler to close, because you need less boilerplate to do so.